# How can I make a function ignore positive numbers in a Google Sheet using Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

For my expense tracker, one of my custom functions in Google Sheets allows users to see how much they have spent on a clothing brand. Here is a picture from the Google Sheet:

[image: Google Sheet]

The following function is used to achieve this:

```js
function perCentBrand(brand){
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var total = 0;
   var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function(row){
    total+=row[1];
     if (row[2].toLowerCase() == brand.toLowerCase()){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  var val = "You spent a total of " + (sum*-1) + " on " + brand + " out of " + (total*-1); 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert(val)
}
```

However, this function also takes into account the positive numbers, which are supposed to be income figures, not expense figures. Therefore, when running the function, this message is displayed:

[image: Alert]

Since positive numbers are taken into account, the total says `-270` when it should be `90`. How can I make the function ignore the positive numbers?

Edit:

Alert after suggested answer:
[image: Updated Alert]

Function after suggested answer:

```js
function perCentBrand(brand){
   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
   var values = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
   var total = 0;
   var sum = 0;
  values.forEach(function(row)
  {
    if(row[1] < 0 )
    {
      total+=row[1];

    }
     else if (row[2].toLowerCase() == brand.toLowerCase()){sum+=row[1]}
  })
  var val = "You spent a total of " + (sum*-1) + " on " + brand + " out of " + (total*-1); 
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
   ui.alert(val)
}
```

Comment: Just wrap the current logic in another condition: `if (row[1] >= 0) { /* total and sum logic */ }`

Comment: @joshmeranda I have updated my post with your feedback, but it does not seem to work. Maybe I implemented it wrongly in the function?

Comment: You're super close, you need to wrap *everything* in the conditional, see James's [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71652593/11548057/) below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row[2] part needs to be a separate if inside the (row[1] < 0) part.  Not an else if.

```
values.forEach(function(row) {
  if (row[1] < 0) {
    total+=row[1];
    if (row[2].toLowerCase() == brand.toLowerCase()) {
      sum+=row[1];
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a shot:

```js
function perCentBrand(brand) {
  const spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  const values = spreadSheet
    .getRange(2, 1, spreadSheet.getLastRow() - 1, spreadSheet.getLastColumn())
    .getValues();

  let total = 0;
  let sum = 0;

  values.forEach((row) => {
    const brandNamesMatch = row[2].toLowerCase() == brand.toLowerCase();
    const valueIsAnExpense = row[1] <= 0;

    if (valueIsAnExpense) {
      const expenseValue = Math.abs(row[1]);

      total += expenseValue;

      if (brandNamesMatch) {
        sum += expenseValue;
      }
    }
  });

  const alertText = `You spent $${sum} out of $${total} on ${brand}`;

  const modal = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  modal.alert(alertText);
}
```